# how to re-write this code using generate statement?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, iverilog

I have a Verilog code which looks something like this.

```
module top (
    .
    .
    input a_2;
    input a_1;
    input a_0;
);
    bottom I_bottom(
                    .
                    .
                   .a(a_2);
                   );
    bottom I_bottom_2(
                       .
                       .
                       .a(a_2);
                      );
    bottom I_bottom_1(
                       .
                       .
                       .a(a_1);
                     );
    bottom I_bottom_0(
                      .
                      .
                      .a(a_0)
                     );
endmodule
```

How do I write this code using a `generate` statement?
Please note that the inputs in `top` are fixed in `top`. I cannot change that to an array like `a[2:0]`.

Answer (score 4):

Create vector to equate with the individual port wires. Then use `generate` and index the vector to get at each signal. This works equally for inputs or outputs.

You do have to build the vector manually, but there is no escape from converting somewhere due to the original requirement to keep the individual port names. At least it is done only once, and done succinctly.

```
module top (
    .
    .
    input a_2;
    input a_1;
    input a_0;
);

wire [4:0]vec_a = {a_4, a_3, a_2, a_1, a_0};
generate genvar i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i=i+1) begin
        bottom I_bottom(
                .
                .
               .a(vec_a[i]);
        );
    end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make explicit the suggestion @toolic made in a comment, you could write an array of instances like so:

```
module top (
    input a_3,
    input a_2,
    input a_1,
    input a_0
);

    bottom I_bottom[3:0] (
                      .a({a_3,a_2,a_1,a_0})
                     );
endmodule
```

Note that I've renamed your instance `I_bottom` to `I_bottom[3]` and connected it to input `a_3`, not `a_2`. I'm not sure if you intended to break the pattern there.

---

I realize that this doesn't answer the question as asked, as it doesn't use the `generate` statement. I think I like the solution that does use `generate` better.

Comment: Neat trick! I did not realize you could do this. It is probably more confusing and less explicit when there are a lot of ports or ports are themselves buses. But for making arrays of simple instances or a lot of them, this method could be quite concise. Putting this in the toolbox in case I need it someday :)